# AlertFragments with android support v4 library

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create custom AlertDialog but I have one problem.

My alert dialog class below:

```
class AddNewDayAlert : DialogFragment
{
    public static AddNewDayAlert NewInstance(Bundle bundle)
    {
        AddNewDayAlert fragment = new AddNewDayAlert();
        fragment.Arguments = bundle;
        return fragment;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.AddNewDayLayout, container, false);

        Button btn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialog_text);
        EditText txt = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.dialog_text);
        btn.Click += delegate
        {
            string day_name;
            if (txt.Text != "" && txt.Text != null)
            {
                day_name = txt.Text;
                Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Sėkmingai pridėta!!!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                Dismiss();
            }

            else
                Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Pamiršote įvesti dienos pavadinimą!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        };

        return view;
    }

}
```

and problem is here:

```
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null)
        {
            ft.Remove(prev);
        }
        ft.AddToBackStack(null);

        AddNewDayAlert fragmentas = AddNewDayAlert.NewInstance(null);
        fragmentas.Show(ft, "dialog");
```

> In the last line I get an error because fragmentas.Show() is using `Android.App.FragmentTransaction` and I am using `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction`.
>
> If I try to use `Android.App.FragmentTransaction` I get error in first line: 
>   [image]

Maybe there is way to convert? What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You are conflicting two different `FragmentTransaction` classes. If you decide to use `Support v4 Fragments`, then you will want to use the `Support v4 FragmentTransaction`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html

You will also need to ensure that you are using a `AppCompatActivity`(Which inherits `FragmentActivity` and has a reference to `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager`) if you go down the v4 route. That way you will have access to `SupportFragmentManager` that is the same type.

EX:

```
[Activity(Label = "App7", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

    }
}
```

Comment: I know, but this is still not working, here ss: https://gyazo.com/84aa39ed9a548fd47f54621db8882aa0

Comment: See my updated answer. You will need to use `AppCompatActivity` and `SupportFragmentManager` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your AddNewDayAlert class should also inherit from V4 DialogFragment

```
class AddNewDayAlert : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment
```